# How to get smooth/uniform Textures in Three.js

Tags: three.js, blender

I am trying to build a shoe designer with help of three.js. Shoe model is exported from Blender as json and then trying to apply image loaded textures.

```
newTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/'+filename);
newTexture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
newTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
newMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: newTexture});
```

Textures are applied good on small parts of shoe: [image]

But not good on larger parts:[image]

if you try the sample
http://sandbox.justaddwater.in/ShoeDesigner44/ (it may take some time to load), and try changing the textures using the top buttons, you will see the textures are not uniform over the faces and appear with lines.

I have also tried the repeat function as per responses of other questions here, but it doesn't helped and even textures details get lost while using repeat.

```
newTexture.wrapS = newTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
newTexture.repeat.set(2,2);
```

Comment: there is an issue with the UV coords of the model.

Comment: @gaitat Can you please provide more information as I am only responsible for frontend and I need more details to discuss this with my graphics designer.

Comment: if you tell him its the uv coords fault ... he will understand.

Answer (score 2):

Your shoe model is not UV-unwrapped properly.
Open you model in blender and unwrap it there, then export the model once again.
There are many tutorials on YouTube that teach how to unwrap meshes properly in Blender.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction, i got this fixed without help of designer.

Using Smart UV project feature did the trick for me:

1. Select your model and switch to edit mode (Tab)
2. Select all (A)
3. Press U> Smart UV Project.

Comment: Exactly! I am happy I could help! =)